# Issue with Content-Range Header in Go and React-admin

Tags: reactjs, rest, go, cors, react-admin

I am facing an issue while developing an application using Go as the backend and React-admin as the frontend. We have created a simple REST API in Go to work with a PostgreSQL database and want to use React-admin to create an admin panel.

The problem we're encountering is related to the Content-Range header in the HTTP response. React-admin expects this header to be present in responses to requests to correctly display paginated data. However, when attempting to fetch user data, the Content-Range header is missing in the response.

**My test API:**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "123"
    dbname   = "orbita"
)

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    // Create a connection to the PostgreSQL database
    connStr := "user=" + user + " password=" + password + " dbname=" + dbname + " sslmode=disable"
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // Configure routes for your REST API
    r.HandleFunc("/users", GetUsers).Methods("GET")
    // Create a CORS instance
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"}, // Allow access from all domains
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"*"}, // Allow all headers
    })

    // Wrap the routes with CORS middleware
    handler := c.Handler(r)

    http.Handle("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

// User structure
type User struct {
    Username     string `json:"username"`
    PasswordHash string `json:"password_hash"`
    FirstName    string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName     string `json:"last_name"`
    Position     string `json:"position"`
    AccessLevel  string `json:"access_level"`
}

// GetUsers returns a list of users from the database
func GetUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT username, password_hash, first_name, last_name, position, access_level FROM users")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var users []User
    for rows.Next() {
        var user User
        if err := rows.Scan(&user.Username, &user.PasswordHash, &user.FirstName, &user.LastName, &user.Position, &user.AccessLevel); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        users = append(users, user)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    // Add the Content-Range header in the format 'users 0-24/324'
    totalUsers := len(users)
    contentRange := fmt.Sprintf("users 0-%d/%d", totalUsers, totalUsers)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Range", contentRange)

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    responseData := map[string]interface{}{"users": users}
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseData)
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import {
  Admin,
  Resource
} from "react-admin";
import { UserList } from "./users";
import { dataProvider } from "./dataProvider";

export const App = () => <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
  <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
</Admin>;
```

**users.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EmailField } from 'react-admin';

export const UserList: React.FC = (props) => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
      <TextField source="username" />
      <EmailField source="email" />
      <TextField source="first_name" label="First Name" />
      <TextField source="last_name" label="Last Name" />
      <TextField source="position" />
      <TextField source="access_level" label="Access Level" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: By default, browsers allow cross-origin clients to access only [a limited set of response headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name), and `Content-Range` is not among them. You'll need to list that header as an [exposed response header](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rs/cors#Options.ExposedHeaders) in your CORS configuration.

Comment: Pssst! Here is a better (IMO) [CORS middleware library](https://github.com/jub0bs/fcors) you can use.

Comment: i'm try this:
 `r := mux.NewRouter()

 cors, err := fcors.AllowAccess(
  fcors.FromAnyOrigin(),
  fcors.WithAnyMethod(),
  fcors.WithAnyRequestHeaders(),
  fcors.MaxAgeInSeconds(30),
 )
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }

 r.HandleFunc("/users", GetUsers).Methods("GET")`
but The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response again

Comment: Ok. One step at a time. Do you see the `Content-Range` header in the response when you inspect it in the Network tab of the DevTools?

Comment: Yes. HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Range: users 0-0/1
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2023 17:57:50 GMT
Content-Length: 198

Comment: Ah I see what's wrong. You forgot to specify that `Content-Range` should be exposed. In your call to `fcors.AllowAccess`, add the following option: `fcors.ExposeResponseHeaders("Content-Range")`.

Comment: All fixed now?...